# Multiple-entry business Schengen visa

Tags: italy

I would like to to find out whether I would be permitted to travel to Spain for tourism purposes if I currently hold a 6-month multiple-entry business Schengen visa issued by the Italian consulate. By the way, my first trip was Italy. I had a business meeting.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen rules do not distinguish between "business" and "tourist" visas.

What you have is a *uniform short-stay visa* for multiple entries. It is valid for an unlimited number of subsequent trips to anywhere in the Schengen area, as long as the purpose of each of the trips is legal (e.g., you can't work).

Note that if the visa displays a "duration of stay" less then 90 of days, this is the *total* number of days you can be present spend in the Schengen area, summed over *all* your trips.

If the "duration of stay" is given as 90 all you have to comply with is the general 90/180 day rule.  (However, in case of a 6-month visa where you haven't had any visa before, that works out the same as max 90 days over the entire 6-month visa validity).

Comment: My visa was issued by the Italian consulate .. I stayed in Italy for 4 days only then I traveled to Barcelona and stayed for 5 days .. would it be okay if I visit Barcelona again ??  I spent most of the time in a country which did not issue the visa

Comment: @Siraj: Which part of "valid for an unlimited number of subsequent trips to anywhere in the Schengen area" is insufficiently clear?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't violated the terms of your visa (like the 90 days in 180 day period rule), your visa is valid, and as long as you can answer simple questions about your trip that you may be asked at the immigration counter, such as "where will you be staying? can you show me a hotel reservation?" and "when will you be leaving? please show me your return flight ticket?" you should be fine.

Don't forget you should also carry other documentation such as valid health insurance for the duration of your trip with you; and your visa must be valid on the day you exit.

Enjoy your trip.

Source: Traveled many times on a multiple entry Schengen visa to states other than those that issued it, for purposes other than what was originally used to obtain the visa.